# Python code works, but eclipse shows error - Syntax error while detecting tuple

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x

I new to python. I use Python 3.3 in Eclipse Kepler.

This is my code snippet:

```
f = Fibonacci(0,1)
for r in f.series():
    if r > 100: break
    print(r, end=' ')
```

At the line `print(r, end = '')`, eclipse reports a syntax 
error - `Syntax error while detecting tuple`. However, the 
program runs perfectly.

Why does this happen and how do I fix the error?

Comment: Eclipse must be calibrated for Python 2.x, in which `print(r, end=' ')` would be illegal syntax.

Comment: @iCodez - I don't understand. I am using py 3.3. So, how does this apply to me ?

Comment: Just because you're using py 3.3 doesn't mean Eclipse knows that.

Comment: I mean, the system that Eclipse is using to check your syntax might be following Python 2.x's syntax rules.  The code you posted is fine for Python 3.x but it would raise a `SyntaxError` in Python 2.x.  In other words, your IDE is causing the problem; the code is fine.  You need to find a way to tell Eclipse to follow Python 3.x's syntax rules.  I do not know how to do this because I do not use Eclipse, so that is why I am commenting instead of posting an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to specify the correct `Grammar Version` in Eclipse. See here: [print function in Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352888/print-function-in-python3?rq=1)

Is `Grammar Version` 3.3 in your setup? Steps - Project > Properties > Python Interpreter/Grammar. You might have to restart Eclipse to see the changes.

Comment: I got my mistake. I went to windows > preferences and set the python INTERPRETER there. It should be Project > Properties > Python Interpreter/Grammar. I had to restart Eclipse to see the changes.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but for those of you with similar issues in 2018 and later, CodeMix for Eclipse is a plugin you can install to boost your python development with almost none configuration needed. You get Content Assist, Validation, shortcut commands for stuff from refactoring to formatting, etc. More informaiton [here](https://www.genuitec.com/tech/python-in-eclipse/)

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.x `print` is a built-in keyword, not a function as in python 3.x and is used like this :

```
>>> print "hello", "world"
hello world
```

Therefore, Python assumes that `(r, end= '')` is a tuple containing two values, that you are trying to print.

You can probably configure eclipse to use python 3.x syntax. Check [this](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) if you are using PyDev.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible you're actually using Python 2. Do this and report your results:

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

---

EDIT:

Actually, what you're reporting appears to be an open bug on pydev for Eclipse:

http://sourceforge.net/p/pydev/bugs/913/

Comment: Is this really an answer to the question? Should it not be a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Change the run path in eclipse to python 3.x rather than its current setting which is probably set to python 2.x

Comment: Can you expand this answer---e.g., why you think Eclipse would be set to use Python 2 versus Python 3, etc. One-sentence answers tend to be frowned on here, even if they contain correct information, and are likely to get converted into comments.