# Print function input into int

Tags: python

My goal is very simple, which makes it all the more irritating that I'm repeatedly failing:

I wish to turn an input integer into a string made up of all numbers within the input range, so  if the input is `3`, the code would be:
`print(*range(1, 3+1), sep="")`

which obviously works, however when using an `n = input()` , no matter where I put the `str()`, I get the same error:

```
"Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"
```

I feel sorry to waste your collective time on such an annoyingly trivial task..

My code:

```
n= input()
print(*range(1, n+1), sep="")
```

I've also tried list comprehensions (my ultimate goal is to have this all on one line):

```
[print(*range(1,n+1),sep="") | n = input() ]
```

I know this is not proper syntax, how on earth am I supposed to word this properly?

[This](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk) didn't help, ditto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352888/print-function-in-python3), ditto [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654168/typeerror-cant-convert-int-object-to-str-implicitly), I give up --> ask S.O.

Comment: Are you sure your input() function is producing an integer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason why you would use `str` here, you should use `int`; the value returned from `input` is of type `str` and you need to transform it.

A one-liner could look like this:

```
print(*range(1, int(input()) + 1), sep=' ')
```

Where `input` is wrapped in `int` to transform the str returned to an `int` and supply it as an argument to `range`.

As an addendum, your error here is caused by `n + 1` in your `range` call where `n` is *still* an `str`; Python *won't* implicitly transform the value held by `n` to an `int` and perform the operation; it'll complain:

```
n = '1'
n + 1 
TypeErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-117-a5b1a168a772> in <module>()
----> 1 n + 1

TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly
```

That's why you need to be *explicit* and wrap it in `int()`. Additionally, take note that the one liner *will* fail with input that can't be transformed to an `int`, you need to wrap it in a `try-except` statement to handle that if needed.

Comment: Was trying to help him see this on his own, but yeah this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you should just be able to do:

```
n = int(input())
print(*range(1,n+1),sep="")
```

But you would also want to have some error checking to ensure that a number is actually entered into the prompt.

A one-liner that works:

```
print(*range(1, int(input()) + 1), sep="")
```